# Recurrence event using rrule in event calendar

Tags: angular, rrule, event-calendar

I have following data

```
data = [
  {
    busy: true,
    status: "confirmed",
    recurrence: {
      rrule: [
        "RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20230602T182959Z;BYDAY=FR,MO,TH,TU,WE;WKST=SU",
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    busy: true,
    status: "confirmed",
    recurrence: {
      rrule: ["RRULE:FREQ=DAILY"],
    },
  },
  {
    busy: true,
    status: "confirmed",
    recurrence: null,
  },
];
```

Using this event calendar

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/@event-calendar/core?activeTab=readme

for recurrence event trying to use this package

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/rrule

for simple event i'm getting events on calendar i want to know how to implement rrule in this calendar